# How one would handle a correlation between raise of medical personell in Britain and incidence of Cancer there, especially in Females?

Tags: cancer

I've made a hypothesis to myself that a raise in "doctor" population also raises "medical interventions" irrespective of severity of patient's conditions. Cancer is usually described as an  "interventionalist" phenomenon, usually related to various substances. Drugs are also "substances".

[image: cancer incidence in Britain]

[image: medpers in Britain]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about what we do here on this Stack. Why wouldn't this be the case? It's all about this correlation: More doctors -> better care -> better diagnosis

Comment: Why the difference between Males and Females?

Comment: Improved care for women. Until relatively recently almost all Drs in the UK were men and women's issues were often marginalized or treated as non-serious, especially if it was something to do with the reproductive tract. However, note that the male incidence is also rising, albeit at a lesser rate.

Comment: Aging population?

Comment: Yes, I've meant trend difference (like "b" in "y=a+b*x"), and not the absolute numbers. The difference in "b" is small, but the significance is usually decidable in research. Do you have a reference to your claim that "since Drs were men women-specific cancers were underdiagnosed"? Then there of course a question of the ratio of women-specific cancers amongst all cancers and its influence on the trend.

Comment: It's commonly observed that increased/improved screening results in more interventions for many diseases. That's one of the reasons why Medicare and insurance companies in the US impose limits on certain screening exams such as colonoscopies. Without question cancer screening technologies have advanced significantly over the last 25 years, and they've become more common. Treatments have also improved significantly, so more people survive cancer, which may recur later, leading to increased diagnoses. The increased number of doctors may be a factor, but I suspect it's not the major one.

Comment: @aleksv google "women's health disparities"!

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks for the overview. Yet the question about "male-female trend disparity" stands. I would probably skip on the hypothesis if trends were very close, as of course "patients per doctor" statistic did decrease, and doctors can examine patients better (more free time).

Comment: I very seriously doubt that if you conducted a survey you would find that doctors have more free time. I think you'd find quite the opposite. As for the male/female disparities, there are more female doctors now, as @bob1 pointed out, and women are more subject to cancer than men due to several organs that men don't have (uterus, cervix) and have less of (breast tissue). I think your hypothesis needs more homework to be anything more than an interesting correlation.

Comment: Doctors have less free time now than ever before across the board, so that aspect of your hypothesis is void. You can't throw out the disparity between the care women have historically received and that which they are receiving now (50 years ago, most doctors - males, of course - believed that women didn't suffer heart attacks!) And as @CareyGregory astutely pointed out, a greater percentage of doctors today are women, who tend to be much more likely to investigate the complaints of women patients than men. I think there is no particular relationship between your two points...

Comment: ...except that more doctors also translates to more female doctors. The quality of medicine has improved overall and more women are being diagnosed and treated.

Comment: So, if no more free time for doctors then more sick people now than in 1997. Why increase in doctor population then?